# Rounding errors in images of Julia sets

Tags: numerical-analysis, floating-point

One typically computes Julia sets by iterating a complex function, such as a polynomial or rational function.

How do rounding errors affect the results?

I'm looking for references on this issue, especially but not exclusively for the escape time method.

The only ones I have found so far are:

- "The [inverse iteration] method is very insensitive to round-off errors, since $f$ tends to be expanding on its Julia set, so that $f^{-1}$ tends to be contracting.'' [Milnor, *Dynamics in one complex variable*, page 49]
- "Theorem 1 makes it plausible that in almost all cases rounding errors do
  not affect the computer graphics of Julia sets.'' [Steinmetz, *Rational iteration*, page 175]

Comment: Cross-posted in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200161/rounding-errors-in-images-of-julia-sets.

Comment: When one wants certified/rigorous results out of a computer, the main technique in dynamical systems is [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). There is active research on this topic; for instance, it was only around 2000 that it was proved that the [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) really exists and is not only a numerical artifact.

Comment: Backward stability of the iteration function is the relevant concept here.

Comment: @Kirill, I'd love to see an actual reference discussing  backward stability of function iteration for complex polynomials.

Comment: Related: [Images of Julia sets that you can trust](webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/serien/e/IMPA_A/721.pdf), De Figuereido et al.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, now published as [Rigorous bounds for polynomial Julia sets](http://dx.doi.org/10.3934/jcd.2016006) in *Journal of Computational Dynamics*.

Comment: @lhf I just checked initials and realized that I probably pointed out a paper to its own author, oops. :)

Answer (score -1):

Can it be proved that the very existance of these convergence / divergence boundaries is stable in the face of numerical rounding artifacts? They seem to bear an uncanny resemblance to quantization error and sinc functions.